# How to store basename of realpath of a softlink to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to set a shell variable for the output of a following command :

```
basename $(realpath $DIR)   //$DIR is a softlink
```

when I do :

```
set FOLDER_NUM=$(basename $(realpath $DIR))
```

and source the script , it says :

> Illegal variable name.

Im expecting to get the folder name of realpath of $DIR into FOLDER_NUM variable .

example :

```
$DIR is "/usr/kate/latest"
realpath $DIR
```

will give /usr/kate/12134

I want to set `FOLDER_NUM=12134`

Comment: You don't use `set` to assign variables. It's just `variable=`

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: WHY did you remove the edit @Barmar made?

Comment: `$DIR = "/usr/kate/latest"` is not correct bash code. It looks more like PHP.

Comment: I meant $DIR is /usr/kate/latest